# How to execute code after an RDD pipe transformation operation

Tags: java, apache-spark

In my sparkJob I execute several transformation and aggregation operations. I have a need of notifying a service before and after a pipe operation. Specifically, referring to the code below, I need to make a service call after "pipe operation 1" has completed on all documents in the RDD and before "pipe operation 2" begins.

```
JavaRDD<Document> stage_y = stage_x.
                map(r -> someRddOperation(r) ).
                pipe( "pipe operation 1 to external process" ).
                map(r -> someMapOps(r) );

// execute something before processing stage_y

JavaRDD<Document> stage_z = stage_y.
                pipe( "pipe operation 2 to another external process" ).
                map(r -> someMapOps(r) );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Spark RDD transformations are not executed until an [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) is called. In your case, neither the `stage_y` nor `stage_z` will be executed at all. You must call an action specifying what you want to do after those transformations.

Once the action called over the `stage_y` RDD has been completed, the code bellow it will be executed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i know the RDD wouldnt be processed until an action is taken, for brevity i didnt include the code after stage_y. But by question still stands, how can i execute a call after stage_x is done and before stage_y begins?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark transformations are lazily evaluated, they return another RDD without running the actual computation. Logical and physical execution plans are created with an action operation (might be a count operation or saving the transformed data to a datastore).

Moreover two map tranformations might create a combined execution plan so that you cannot differentiate which operation is executing first.

If you really need to call an external process in a specific stage you might consider saving the intermediate rdd result to a datastore and running the external process.